# automake: error: cannot open < maintMakefile: No such file or directory

Tags: ubuntu, makefile, automake

I'm trying to compile 5 versions of *GNU make* on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, including 3.76.1 and 3.80.

When I use `make`, it return error like following:

```
cd . && aclocal
aclocal: warning: autoconf input should be named 'configure.ac', not 'configure.in'
configure.in:35: warning: underquoted definition of AC_CHECK_SYMBOL
configure.in:35:   run info Automake 'Extending aclocal'
configure.in:35:   or see http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/automake.html#Extending-aclocal
cd . && automake --gnu --include-deps Makefile
automake: warning: autoconf input should be named 'configure.ac', not 'configure.in'
configure.in:6: warning: AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE: two- and three-arguments forms are deprecated.  For more info, see:
configure.in:6: http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/automake.html#Modernize-AM_005fINIT_005fAUTOMAKE-invocation
configure.in:15: error: required file './compile' not found
configure.in:15:   'automake --add-missing' can install 'compile'
automake: error: cannot open < maintMakefile: No such file or directory
Makefile:135: recipe for target 'Makefile.in' failed
make: *** [Makefile.in] Error 1
```

Then, to figure out the error, I install the automake and and use `automake --add-missing`, then the first error disappears. However, there are still one error:

```
cd . && automake --gnu --include-deps Makefile
automake: warning: autoconf input should be named 'configure.ac', not 'configure.in'
configure.in:6: warning: AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE: two- and three-arguments forms are deprecated.  For more info, see:
configure.in:6: http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/automake.html#Modernize-AM_005fINIT_005fAUTOMAKE-invocation
automake: error: cannot open < maintMakefile: No such file or directory
Makefile:135: recipe for target 'Makefile.in' failed
make: *** [Makefile.in] Error 1
```

How to fix it? Hope someone can help me.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  What exactly do you do?  You try to compile different versions of make and these all fail in the same way?  If so, I would focus on one of the versions (say, the most recent), and mention that certain other versions give the same error.

Comment: Thank you for help, 3.75 has no error. When I try to compile 3.76.1, 3.77， 3.78.1, 3.79 and 3.80, the error arise.
I got these 6 old versions of make from a paper's code, I am not sure if it was edited. The link of paper is  [Comparing White-box and Black-box Test Prioritization](http://henard.net/research/regression/ICSE_2016/), and I use it's subject programs.

Comment: I don't see any downloadable `make` implementation in the link you gave. So I downloaded [GNU make 3.80](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/make/make-3.80.tar.bz2), but there is no `Makefile` to be run directly. Running `./configure && make` works without problems. So I'm not entirely sure where your problem lies. *what exactly* are you trying to compile (please give a link to the downloadable project files)?

Comment: Ok, you can try this [subject_programs.zip](http://henard.net/research/regression/ICSE_2016/subject_programs.zip) and there are 5 subjects in the zip file. `make` is one of them. there will be 7 versions of `make`, v0, v0_gcov, v1, v2, v3, v4,v5. Both v1-v5 has this error.
Thank you.